# Apache Camel: Wait for a group of files and then process as batch

Tags: file, routes, apache-camel, polling

I'm looking for advice on how to set up a Camel route.  Basically, I need to wait for a given list of files to be created and then process them all together as a single unit.  Here's my scenario:

1. A `request-manifest.xml` is generated into `Incoming/Requests` by an external process.  This file lists a set of files to be processed as a unit.
2. Sometime afterwards, these files are generated into `Incoming/Parts` by another external process.  These files are created in parallel and thus may show up in any order at various times, but generally within a few minutes of each other.
3. The complete batch is then processed as a unit (e.g. zipped and FTP'd, copied to another location, etc.)

Conceptually, I've worked out two possible approaches:

1. Transform and split the manifest into individual ManifestItems that are then each enriched in parallel and then rejoined together into a completed Batch.
2. Poll `Incoming/Parts` and enrich each file message with its batch-id, then aggregate them into a completed Batch

The first approach uses the [Composed Message Processor](http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html) pattern, although I'm not sure how to get the ManifestItems enrichment to wait in parallel, and I don't know if it will scale well if the system is waiting for hundreds or thousands of files.  Conceptually it seems simpler, with just one route.

The second approach is more-event driven (even though the file endpoint polls, it abstracts it away from us), but it seems more complex.  It would have two routes, one to process the manifests and one to process the parts, and seem to require some temporary storage (in-memory database?) that accumulates data on the incoming requests in order to associate each file to its batch when it appears.

Do either of these seem like good approaches?  What's the most "Cameline" way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some control over the external applications, you can let them generate a 3rd file when they finished generating the needed files. You can then use the option `doneFileName` to start processing the files. See [Camel Docs of *file* component](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html#File2-Consumer) - the options are also valid for the *ftp* component.

Comment: That would probably work in some situations, but in mine, the processes generating the individual files don't know about each other and don't know when the entire batch is ready.